# Dynkin System Generated by Collection of Subsets

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to reconcile in my mind the two definitions of a Dynkin system generated by a collection $\mathcal{G}$ as shown on [Wikiproof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Dynkin_System_Generated_by_Collection_of_Subsets).

So, the first one says that $\delta(\mathcal{G})$ is the smallest d-system generated by $\mathcal{G}$. I understand that part. The alternative definition however says explicitly that any other d-system that $\mathcal{G}$ is part of must also contain $\delta(\mathcal{G})$. How come the two statements are equivalent - isn't it possible for $\delta(\mathcal{G})$ and another d-system to contain $\mathcal{G}$ without the former being a subset of the later?

Answer (score 1):

What's going on is that the intersection of a non-empty family of d-systems
is a d-system. Then $\delta(G)$ is the intersection of all d-systems $D$
with $G\subseteq D$ (since that $\delta(G) $ must be a d-system).
 This means that if $D$ is a d-system with $D\supseteq G$
then $D\supseteq \delta(G)$.

Comment: Ok... somewhat starts to clear up. I guess by G-system, you mean a d-system span by G, right?